# AnyLogic: Use arrival table and a parameter database together in one source block

Tags: simulation, anylogic

for an analysis of a production process, I want to spawn agents in my source block according to past real data.

For that, I want to use an arrival table to make sure that the agents spawn at the correct time.
But I also need to give my agents different parameter variations.

For that, I want to use the "Set agent parameters from DB" checkmark.

However, it seems that I can't use both of them combined. Is there a way to use an arrival table and a parameter DB combined?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to use a single table for all the information regarding the agent.

[image]

See the example table below

You also need to create a customer agent for your source with parameters you want to populate from the DB

[image]

Then in the source you can select to generate this agent at the "new Agent" dropdown. Then you will be able to populate all the agent parameters from table you specified

[image]